# Permanent Location for Server?

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client

I have a server and client that I built in C++. To connect to it, I have to know the port and IP Address.

My problem is that I don't want to have change my code every single time I move to a different place (and my IP address changes), or I change my port.

Is there any way I can make a permanent location/home for my server? So that no matter what, my clients can connect to a specific place.

I was considering making my IP address static, but then I would still have to change my code if I ever get a new computer, or I move my server elsewhere.

Comment: Get a [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) provider and use a DDNS hostname. Also, consider using a configuration system instead of hardcoding endpoints.

Comment: Just FYI, getting a new computer won't change a static IP address. If your Internet modem is connected directly to the computer, it will pick up the same IP. If the modem is connected to a router, then the IP is assigned to the router, not the computer.

Comment: K thanks for the help I just got a dynamic DNS

Comment: I got a dynamic DNS from noIP but the ip address they give is different fron the one on my computer. I used DUC40 to keep my ip address up to date but it still isn't the same one that is on my computer.

Comment: @ShovaCode the whole point of using a DDNS service is that your computer is supposed to upload its current IP to the service periodically, so that if the IP changes then your DDNS hostname will reflect that. The DDNS service does not assign an IP to your computer. Is your computer attached to a router? If so, you have to upload the router's WAN IP, not the computer's LAN IP.